# how to select default items in angular material 2 select multiple

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm working on angular 2 material app, I have a case where there is multiselect element and in that I have a list with checkbox so I can select multiple items at a time. I'm able to to that with angular material component, but what I want is 2-3 items to be checked by default, and if I select/deselect a particular item, then I should get checked/selected flag as true/false.

```
<md-select multiple="true" [(mgModel)]="test">
  <md-option *ngFor="let l of list" [value]="l">
    {{l.name}}
  </md-option>
</md-select>

var list = [{name:'abc'},{name:'cbv'},{name:'hgf'},{name:'rty'},{name:'fdv'},{name:'vbg'}]

var test = [{{name:'abc'},{name:'cbv'}]
```

Is there some other way around or m going wrong some where.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? What's happening when you open the page? Does it break? Are there errors? Are your items just not checked? Are wrong items checked?

Comment: None of my items are checked

Comment: If your are using **reactive Form** here is a answer [compareWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162580/angular-5-angular-material-select-reactive-forms-no-initial-options-displ/57215741#57215741)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you bind `object` to `option` of `select`, angular will compare default value and option's value by object instance. Here `{name: 'abc'}` and `{name:'cbv'}` of `list` and `test` have the same filed and value, but they keep different instance. So none will be setted to `selected`.

@yurzui's answer will work by keeping same object instance at both arrays.

Another solution(which you don't need to keep the same instance of object) is using **`compareWith`** directive, see [**docs**](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#caveat-option-selection). This way you should implement a compareWith Function to tell angular how to compare between objects.

```
<md-select multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="test" [compareWith]="compareWithFunc">
  <md-option *ngFor="let l of list" [value]="l">
    {{l.name}}
  </md-option>
</md-select>

compareWithFunc(a, b) {
  return a.name === b.name;
}
```

see **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7s4hrb?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.html)**.

Comment: This should be answer..!!

Answer (score 4):

Your `test` array should contain elements from `list` array:

```typescript
list = [{name:'abc'},{name:'cbv'},{name:'hgf'},{name:'rty'},{name:'fdv'},{name:'vbg'}];

test = this.list.slice(0,2);
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/LzzSPeyBEn4vvu2QAgGl?p=preview)**