# Angular 5 + Angular Material Select + Reactive Forms == No initial options displayed

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

As the title says, I have a reactive form that has multiple `<mat-select>` contained within. On initial form load, the initial option is not displayed even though `form.value` shows it is.

Pertinent component.ts:

```
export class DesJobInfoEditComponent implements OnInit {

...

currentJobData: IJob;
jobTypes: IJobType[];

...

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    ...

        // Construct forms
        this.createForm();

        this.initializeForm();

}

createForm() {
    this.editJobInfoForm = this.fb.group({
        ...
        JobType: '', // mat-select
        ...
    });
}

initializeForm() {
    this.rebuildForm();
}

rebuildForm() {
    this.editJobInfoForm.reset({
        ...
        JobType: this.jobTypes[this.currentJobData.JobType].DisplayDesc,
        ...
    });
}
```

}

Pertinent html:

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex>
      <mat-label>Job Type</mat-label>
       <mat-select formControlName="JobType" placeholder="Job Type">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let jobType of jobTypes" value="jobType.value">
                     {{ jobType.DisplayDesc }}
               </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

When the form loads, the selects do not display the initially selected option, however, they are set properly, apparently:

```
Form value { ... "JobType": "0 - Standard", ... }
```

All that displays on the form is the placeholder.

This seems like it should not be this difficult.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

`this.jobTypes` is loaded when the module is loaded, and it is a BehaviorSubject that lives in my data service. I subscribe to it in the constructor of this component thusly:

`this.data.jobTypes.subscribe(jobTypes => { this.jobTypes = jobTypes });`

Comment: Maybe you need to pipe async? `let jobType of jobTypes | async`

Comment: How are you loading jobTypes?  I don't see the code that populates this.jobTypes

Comment: @Stanton I have updated my question.

Comment: have you had any updates on this? I'm having the exact same problem... When I change to a simple HTML select everything works fine...

    <select formControlName="category" [compareWith]="compareFn">
        <option [ngValue]="c" *ngFor="let c of categoriesService.categories$ | async"> {{c.name}}</option>
      </select>

Answer (score 13):

A few things

1. `[formControlName]` *must* be used in conjunction with `[formGroup]`. If you don't want to use `[formControlName]` + `[formGroup]`, you can use `[formControl]` instead.
2. In angular, there is a difference between specifying an attribute as `value` and `[value]`. When an attribute is enclosed in brackets `[]`, it is interpreted as <strike>javascript /</strike> angular template script (same as `{{}}`, I think). When it is *not* enclosed in brackets, it is interpreted as a string (i.e. `value="jobType.value"` === `[value]="'jobType.value'"` and `[value]="jobType.value"` === `value="{{jobType.value}}"` (actually I think there are subtle differences between `[value]="jobType.value"` and `value="{{jobType.value}}"`, but w/e)). So when you write `<mat-option *ngFor="let jobType of jobTypes" value="jobType.value">`, the value of every `mat-option` is `"jobType.value"` which, I imagine, isn't want you want. So you need to change the code to `<mat-option *ngFor="let jobType of jobTypes" [value]="jobType.value">`

e.g.

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]='editJobInfoForm' fxFlex>
  <mat-label>Job Type</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="JobType" placeholder="Job Type">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let jobType of jobTypes" [value]="jobType.value">
      {{ jobType.DisplayDesc }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Somewhat unrelated to your problem, why have both `createForm()` and `initializeForm()` methods? Why not simply

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    ...

        // Construct forms
        this.createForm();    
}

createForm() {
    this.editJobInfoForm = this.fb.group({
        ...
        JobType: this.jobTypes[this.currentJobData.JobType].DisplayDesc,
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Very well explained – my compliments!

Answer (score 7):

Angalural Material compareWith: (o1: any, o2: any) => boolean from (API reference for Angular Material select)

component.ts

```
 export class ParentOneComponent implements OnInit {
  materialFormSample: FormGroup;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.configureMaterialFormSample();
  }
  name: string = 'Emilius Patrin Mfuruki';
  toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
  selectedToppingList = ['Extra cheese', 'Tomato', 'Onion'];

  compareWithFunc = (a: any, b: any) => a == b;

  configureMaterialFormSample() {
    this.materialFormSample = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(this.name),
      toppings: new FormControl(this.selectedToppingList)
    })
  }
  onSubmitForm() {
    if (this.materialFormSample.valid) {
      console.log('submitting Form Content Valid', this.materialFormSample.value);
    }
  }
}
```

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="materialFormSample" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()" autocomplete="off">
      <mat-form-field class="w-100">
        <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field class="w-100">
        <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="toppings" multiple [compareWith]="compareWithFunc">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" class="float-right">Submit Form</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use compare with function as it is ...

Step1: put [compareWith] tag as it is shown

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Pick item..." formControlName="selectedItem" 
    [compareWith]="compareFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{item.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<button (click)="changeValue()">Change value</button>
```

Stet 2 : declare variable `compareFn`  and function `compareByValue` as shown below no changes required

```
compareFn: ((f1: any, f2: any) => boolean) | null = this.compareByValue;

compareByValue(f1: any, f2: any) { 
  return f1 && f2 && f1.name === f2.name; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I know its too much late but I know a simpler solution.
Your U I (html) components are described correctly

in your typescript you are comparing object with string which will not produce any validation.
So  always compare objects with null (in validation)

simply in `createForm() {
    this.editJobInfoForm = this.fb.group({
        ...
        JobType: '', // mat-select
        ...
    });
}`

change `JobType: ''` replace with `JobType:[null]`